# In which condition is it stationary?

Tags: statistics

A continuous time process it's nule for t < 0. In which conditions is it stationary (WSS)?

I know that E[x(t)] must be a constant and the autocorrelation function must depend only on the time difference t2-t1. Are there any other conditions?

Comment: There is wide sense and strict stationarity. What you said is wide sense stationarity. Elsewhere wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: No, these are the only conditions for second order stationarity.

Answer (score 0):

Wide-sense stationarity (WSS) need only two conditions that you mentioned, that is $E(X(t))$ is independent of $t$, and the $Cov(X(t_1),X(t_2))=|t_1-t_2|$.
See also, 
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopencourses.emu.edu.tr%2Fmod%2Fresource%2Fview.php%3Fid%3D170%26redirect%3D1&ei=EWBeVI6zI8PiuQSq_4LYDg&usg=AFQjCNEUdGXXR8OyxLWyRPB6kcv1NBME0g&bvm=bv.79189006,d.c2E

Answer (score 0):

**Condition for stationarity:**

1. No trend in data
2. No change in variance